# Converting rows with the same value into column headers

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to convert my data, so that all the rows with the same data gets grouped into column headers with the information listed under them.  I've attached an example of my problem. Is it possible to do what I'm asking in the power query, or does it need to be done in the visuals? I'm ok with either option.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried pivoting and transposing so far and I can't seem to get it to work. I've also tried using a Matrix table in the visuals, however it will only give me one value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Add sample data and the expected results based on the sample data.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I've added a sample of what I'm looking to achieve. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. The secret is to group and add an index within the group.

So, right click and group on feeder, and choose operation all rows

then change the

```
each _, type table [...]}})
```

to

```
each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}})
```

expand the index and turbine using arrows atop the new column, click on feeder, and pivot turbine as the value

sample full code:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Feeder"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Turbine", "Index"}, {"Turbine", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded data"[Feeder]), "Feeder", "Turbine"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in   #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: If this solved your issue, please toggle the checkmark to accept the answer